Does /tə/ sound like /d/?
/t/ is voiceless, while /d/ is voiced. If I place the voiced vowel /ə/ after /t/, does /tə/ sound like /d/? For example, in "water" /ˈwɔːtər/, it sounds like /ˈwɔːdər/. However, in "doctor" /ˈdɑːktər/, why doesn't it change to /ˈdɑːkdər/? I also don’t feel that /tə/ sounds like /d/.

In general American English, /t/s that occur between vowels become flapped, similar to /d/. That applies to "water", but not "doctor".
However, /t/s that begin unstressed syllables are generally unaspirated, and unaspirated stops are not actively distinguished from voiced ones. So "doctor" arguably does sound very similar to "docdor" in AmE.

british-english
In many British accents, and particularly in the South-Eastern accent that is generally taught to English Learners, the "t" in words like "water" remains voiceless, and not like /d/, which is a voiced.
When placed before a stressed vowel, "t" is normally aspirated. When placed before an unstressed vowel, the "t" may be unaspirated. This can be a particular issue for users of Pinyin, as the glyph "t" is used for the aspirated vowel and "d" for the unaspirated vowel (regardless of voicing) And so if you have learned Latin letters for writing Chinese, you probably think of the sound in "water" as an unaspriated "d", as this is how that sound would be notated in Chinese.
In some less formal dialects it is very common for such "t" sounds to be formed as a glottal stop. The "r" is also not pronounced unless the following sound blends to a vowel. So "water" is pronounced as if it was "wo'e(r)".

Practice your pronuciation with this helpful example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uz9_YfIQaz4 (joke)

What could you mean by 'the "t" in words like "water" remains voiceless',please? That reads as though you hear 'water' as something like 'wor-er' - which surely isn't heard in your link.

in RP, British English, the "t" in water is unvoiced.  It is pronounced as a voiceless dental stop. As the "er" is unstressed, the "t" in water is generally unaspirated.  In some BrE dialects (such as Cockney) the "t" is "dropped" and pronouned as a glottal stop.  Learners should aim to use the standard "unaspirated voiceless dental stop" in words like water. You should be able to hear the difference between the standard pronunciation that the girl uses at the start of the video in my link, and the non-standard that she is using at the end. (the joke is that she is learning to speak cockney)

Thanks James and does that boil down to foxiris really Asking about British 'water' or even 'war-er' as opposed to the 'warder' heard in some US American accents, or did I wholly miss everything.
Either way, I suggest that though clearly the two overlap, the Question belongs somewhere dealing with phonetics, not ELL.
